# Can't boot into windows because I always get a different BSOD

Tags: windows, boot, bsod, windows-11

today I tried to boot in my Microsoft Surface Pro 7 running Windows (and Linux in Dualboot). I can't get it to boot Windows and even if I manage to do it, after I log in (and sometimes even while logging in) I get a BSOD. I tried everything from the MS page and some other websites but it does not work.

In total I got these BSODs:

- SPECIAL_POOL_DETECTED_MEMORY_CORRUPTION
- SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (caused by win32kfull.sys)
- KERNEL_SECURITY_CHECK_FAILURE
- SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION (caused by Ntfs.sys)
- DRIVER_VERIFIER_DMA_VIOLATION
- UNEXPECTED_STORE_EXCEPTION
- ATTEMPTED_EXECUTE_OF_NOEXECUTE_MEMORY

I also could not uninstall the latest function-/qualityupdate.

```
DISM.exe [...] && sfc /scannow
```

Didn't find anything broken/corrupted

Thanks for your time!
Leonardo

Comment: You will have to help us and translate the error into English. However, that appears to be a, memory issue.

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: This is usually caused by a bad memory stick.

Comment: “I also could not uninstall the latest function-/qualityupdate.“ - Why? Can you provide more detail?

Comment: It says this text for both types:

Because of a problem you cannot uninstall the latest update. Instead try to reset your PC (Troubleshooting > Reset this PC). Also sorry for the late reply.

Answer (score 0):

You either have bad hardware or your Windows installation is very broken.

For starters, I would suggest running
[MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)
for as many hours as you can give it.

If MemTest86 finds no errors, you will need to do a Repair Install.

The following Windows 10 tutorial can be used (with adjustments
for Windows 11):
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If your Surface is still under warranty, consider using it.

Comment: I will try it, thanks.

Comment: If your Surface is still under warranty, consider using it.

Comment: It actually is (for 2 more months) but I need it every day and sending it in would take at least 2 weeks (thats what they told me).

Comment: If it keeps giving you trouble, don't miss the last date.

Comment: And submit the issue in writing ASAP, to show it began while under warranty.

Comment: Thanks for your advices!